# Create database tables when wordpress plugin is activated

Tags: php, wordpress

I have develop a plugin that need a table on database and a function that create this table on activation:

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
global $mva_db_version;
$mva_db_version = '1.0';

function Setup_on_activation(){
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) )
        return;
    $plugin = isset( $_REQUEST['plugin'] ) ? $_REQUEST['plugin'] : '';
    check_admin_referer( "activate-plugin_{$plugin}" );

    global $wpdb;
    $db_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table_test';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST $db_name (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      title text NOT NULL,
      content text NOT NULL,
      shortcode text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
    add_option( 'mva_db_version', $mva_db_version );
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'Setup_on_activation');
```

I have followed the same example as [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins), but this it doesnt create me a table on the database, is there any probleme with my code?

I add the following picture to show you the error displayed when activating plugin:
[image: error activationg plugin]

Comment: you're not executing the query, unless `dbDelta()` is taking care of that?

Comment: In the example in the documentation link it shows the same code executed correctly!

Comment: ah ok. Well, I'm not familiar with that function. Check for errors and see what comes of it.

Comment: add in `config.php`: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );`; for display error

Comment: @SimoneNigro: nothing happened...same error !

Comment: Do you get any error, If you remove this DB table function from plugin and activate the plugin?

Comment: @WaliHassan: no there is no error !